# When pushing an array into another one, how to prevent flattening?

Tags: javascript, arrays, extendscript

I would expect this:

```
var x = [1,2];
var y = [3,4];
x.push(y);
x
```

to yield this:

```
[1,2,[3,4]]
```

But some implementations (1) yield this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Why? And how can I get the first result?

1. InDesign 8.1 ExtendScript; some `'/usr/bin/js'` on OSX 10.10.5 that I can’t identify (doesn’t respond to `man`, `version()` or `--version`).

Comment: It should yield the first result unless you use `concat`

Comment: Please, share the name of this browser with us.

Comment: I get this using either
• InDesign 8.1 ExtendScript;
• a '/usr/bin/js' that I can’t identify, on OSX 10.10.5.

I just tried in Chrome and I get the first result.

Comment: Just a guess: Does x.push( [y] ) work?

Comment: `x.push( [y] )` yields the same result: `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: The way Extendscript prints the result is diffrent then the browser.. Just look in the Data Browser, and see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run this code, you get the first result([1,2,[3,4]]), but if you print this in html, you see as the second result.
You can try to see it in console.log
In this JSFiddle you can try it: https://jsfiddle.net/gjLdb4rq/1/ (see the console log)

```
  var x = [1,2];
  var y = [3,4];
  x.push(y);
  console.log(x); //here prints in the console the [1,2,[3,4]]
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=x; //here prints in the html the [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Indeed I misinterpreted the printed result, as the following :

    `var x = [1,2];   var y = [3,4];   x.push(y);   x[2]`

yields [3,4] as expected. Actually no brackets were output at all, which was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It does yield the first result:

```
[1,2,[3,4]]
```